# Selection Sort Algorithm using small array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, selection

Ive been working on selection sort algorithms, just wanted to know the step by step method on working out using the selection sort algorithm.

Just wanted to know if the below is correct

```
Array: 6, 20, 12, 8
```

1st phase: n=0  6, 20, 12, 8 (no swap)

2nd phase: n=1  6, 8, 12, 20

3rd phase: n=2  6, 8, 12, 20 (no swap)

Comment: You have the correct understanding

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You are right

```
  arr[] = 6, 20, 12, 8

// Find the minimum element in arr[0...3]
// and place it at beginning
// 6 is minimum and at its place so no swap
 6, 20, 12, 8

// Find the minimum element in arr[1...3]
// and place it at beginning of arr[1...3]
// 8 is minimum and so swap it with index at 1
 6, 8, 12, 20

// Find the minimum element in arr[2...3]
// and place it at beginning of arr[2...3]
//Every thing is at place no swap 
 6, 8, 12, 20
```